# Вложенные циклы с запросами в mysql (базу)

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть вот такой вот код:

```
$unique_country = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM data_base"; // узнаем уникальные страны
```

Далее узнаем игры в этой стране и к каждой игре узнаем состав команд:

```
while($uc_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unique_country)) {
    $game = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE country='".$uc_result['country']."'"; //скажем, ближайшие игры этой страны
    while($g_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($game)) {
        $players_for_game_team_1 = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE game='".$g_result['id']."' AND TEAM='1'"; //состав на игру команды 1
        $players_for_game_team_2 = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE game='".$g_result['id']."' AND TEAM='2'";  //состав на игру команды 2
        while($team1_players = mysqli_fetch_assoc(...
        while($team2_...
    }
}
```

То-есть получается, что к цикле есть цикл в котором происходит каждый раз запрос в базу, а то и по 2-3 запроса в базу и по несколько циклов, правильное ли это решение? Есть более лучшее решение (к примеру будет ли этом правильно сделать через вложенные запросы и как их разобрать с помощью php)? Если да, напишите, пожалуйста, хотя бы коротко о главном, а то нигде не могу найти подобной информации... буду очень благодарен, а то не знаю правильно ли так делать и остановился, что бы двигаться дальше...

Если сделать вложенные запрос то получится примерно такой результат:

```
страна1 | игра1 | команда1 игрок 1 для игры1 | команда2 игрок 1 для игры1
страна1 | игра1 | команда1 игрок 2 для игры1 | команда2 игрок 2 для игры1
страна1 | игра1 | команда1 игрок 3 для игры1 | команда2 игрок 3 для игры1

страна1 | игра2 | команда1 игрок 1 для игры1 | команда2 игрок 1 для игры1
```

как такой вложенный запрос забирать с помощью php?

Answer (score 1):

Данный код повысит нагрузку как на базу, так и на сам интерпретатор.

В Вашем случае нужно анализировать сам запрос и оптимизировать его.

Ссылки к прочтению:

1. [MySQL JOIN](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html)
2. [Вложенные SELECT](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ANSI_diff_Sub-selects.html)

**UPD:**
Возможно автору нужна документация с примерами: [Пример работы с запросом в виде ассоциативного массива](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

По ссылке приведен пример, как забирать результат в виде ассоциативного массива. Ассоциативный массив — массив с ключами в виде названия столбцов (конкретно эта ситуация), вместо цифровых значений.

**UPD2:**

Прошу прощения, не заметил у автора в коде отсутствие исполнения запроса: `$result = $mysqli->query($game)`. Эта строка будет "говорить" php исполнить запрос, содержащийся в переменной `$game`.

Для более полного понимания ситуации, ознакомьтесь внимательно с приведенными примерами в документации по ссылкам!

Comment: видимо не совсем вы внимательно прочитали вопрос.

Comment: А что не так? Коротко, о главном...

Comment: Что такое вложенные запросы я читал, я не могу понять как разбирать такой запрос в php, о этом я написал в своем вопросе...

Comment: изменил вопрос выше...

Comment: @user3737786, все правильно написано. Вам нужны такие игроки, которые есть в такой игре, которая есть в одной из всех стран. Джойним игроков к играм, игры к странам, применяем нужные фильтры и сортируем.

Comment: Можете написать пример обработки такого запроса на php? Сам запрос не нужен. Обработать результат такого запроса как?

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример из документации

Comment: да в моем примере много чего не хватает, много где стоит троеточие! Вы пишете больше текста о документации и про документацию нежели какой-то небольшой реальный пример, как такой запрос написать, отправить, обработать и вывести на экран... и опять же вы здесь, что бы тыкать ссылки на документацию? что вы хотите таким образом показать? ссылки на документацию я и сам могу найти...

Comment: Я считаю, что от многих вопросов спасает документация, в которой написано как и что делать. Если программист, даже начинающий, пренебрегает ей, ни к чему хорошему это не приведет.

Comment: Никто ей не пренебрегает, в документации нету примеров на все ситуации..